# Mathematical function where slow increase at start and fast increase at end

Tags: algorithm, math, data-modeling, polynomial-math

I have number x=[0,n], where n>0.
I want to construct a function y=f(x) such that the value increase slowly from 0 and increase very fast when approaching n, and when reach n, y is infinity. What is a good function to model this?

Comment: Those are the same function algebraically :)

Comment: Alright.. How about e^(x/n-x) - 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1/(n-x) - 1/n` will work.

There are plenty of other functions log, atan, x^(-k),... that goes to infinity at some point.

`a^y` is another set of functions with fast grows - maybe more suitable for coding as it can reach arbitrary large (but finite) values.

Comment: at x=0, you get 1/n which is why I subtracted 1/n in my comment above. Here's a graph, too: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D1%2F%285-x%29-1%2F5